# How to round up number in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Let's say we have an array of nubmers

```
 $9,333.00 
 $5,733.00 
 $21,333.00 
 $21,833.00
```

How can we make them round up to

```
 $9,500.00 
 $6,000.00 
 $25,500.00 
 $22,000.00
```

Comment: I assume example 3 is a typo. 21,333 rounds to 25,000, should that be 21,500?

Comment: I agree here with @barryhoudini, I don't think the data you have is possible

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Excel's [ceiling function](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/ceiling-HP005209007.aspx) can do this:
If 9333 were in A1, the formula `=ceiling(a1,500)` would return 9500.

Answer (score 1):

If the numbers are in A1 to A4, place

```
=INT((A1+499)/500)*500
```

in B1 and copy this formula down.

This rounds to the nearest 500.  Replace 499 by N-1 and 500 by N to round to the nearest N.